# Zend Framework on nginx problems 404 not found

Tags: php, zend-framework, nginx

I have a web using Zend Framework v1 and nginx running on GNU/Linux Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal. This is my config at /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
upstream php-handler {
        #server 127.0.0.1:9000;
        server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        #root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        root /var/www;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name cloud.weduzedan.go.id;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

# cloud.gemblung.co.id
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name cloud.gemblung.co.id;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last;
                }
        }

        location ~ ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
                try_files $uri = 404;

                include fastcgi_params;
                #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$1;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $2;
                fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
                fastcgi_pass php-handler;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
       }

}
```

Error from the logs are **open() "/var/www404" failed (2: No such file or directory)"**. The browser show "404 not found". How to fix it ?.

Comment: `=404` must be without space.

Comment: @AlexeyTen still blank page with 404 not found but there is no error in log now

Comment: What address do you try to access?

Comment: its in my local server. http://cloud.gemblung.co.id/bpsys. In apache normally it will redirect to http://cloud.gemblung.co.id/bpsys/www/auth as a login page

Comment: As I can see it will be rewrited to `/index.php`. Do you have file `/var/www/index.php`?

Comment: You right @AlexeyTen i don't have index.php in /var/www. So what rule/block i have to write to make point to http://cloud.gemblung.co.id/bpsys ?

Comment: Fix `root` directive to point to root of your application.